# Cloud Firestore , read data collection in doc (user uid)

Tags: php, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have an inventory mobile application using firebase firestore for the database. I want to create a web to display all the products that have been entered by the user (authenticated), how can I read the data in a doc (user uid) for the "product" collection in my database (without any login on the web that I want to create) ? I'm having a hard time finding a way out

[image]

this my role in firebase firestore
[image]

Comment: You wanted to get all data inside on one collection which on the products? can u show that also, Also i think on the document field should also have a uid save which you can determin ethe data you wanted to get for a single data of a certain user using ther uid(authenticated)

Comment: at first, i intend to show all "products" from all users, but i don't know how to do the read process, and i just think to use display products from a certain user uid, can it be done sir (with a note, web that I made it directly display it without any authentication process such as logging in)? for example I call with db.collection('Data').doc('xxxxUSER_UIDxxxx').collection('product')